# Turf.js merge looks for features in GeoJSON

Tags: node.js, leaflet, mapbox, geojson, turfjs

I'm building a mapping app with Node.js.  We have about 40,000 polygons that display on the map so I'm trying to improve performance by merging them where possible.  Turf.js has a merge function that seems like the ticket.  I haven't been able to get it to work though.

Here is the code where I'm trying to use turf in my controller.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var turf = require('turf');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.show = function(req, res) {
  res.render('map', {
    title: 'Map'
  });
};


exports.postSearch = function(req, res) {

  // Bunch of query stuff goes into array below, (omitted for post)

  mongoose.model('Claim').find({
    $and:array
    }, function(err, polygons){
        // fs.writeFile('poly.txt', polygons);
        var test = turf.merge(polygons);
        res.json(test);
    });
};
```

I put that fs.writeFile in there to get a sample of the geojson returned from mongodb.  This is what I get:

```
{
  properties: {
    TTLTPCD: 'CL',
    RNHCTRS: 389,
    TNRTPCD: 'C'
  },
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [
      [Object]
    ],
    type: 'Polygon'
  },
  type: 'Feature',
  _id: '56d2a2061c601e547e1099ee'
}, {
  properties: {
    TTLTPCD: 'CS',
    RNHCTRS: 261,
    TNRTPCD: 'C'
  },
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [
      [Object]
    ],
    type: 'Polygon'
  },
  type: 'Feature',
  _id: '56d2a2071c601e547e109d37'
},
// this repeats a couple hundred times on my test query.
```

I get a stack trace but it doesn't make sense to me:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER/node_modules/turf/node_modules/turf-merge/index.js:55
  var merged = clone(polygons.features[0]),
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports [as merge] (/media/ng/DATA/LighthouseLabs/ClaimMaps/nodeMaps/MapEmGems/node_modules/turf/node_modules/turf-merge/index.js:55:39)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/media/ng/DATA/LighthouseLabs/ClaimMaps/nodeMaps/MapEmGems/controllers/map.js:75:14)
    at /media/ng/DATA/LighthouseLabs/ClaimMaps/nodeMaps/MapEmGems/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /media/ng/DATA/LighthouseLabs/ClaimMaps/nodeMaps/MapEmGems/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:430:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:13)
```

Turf seems to be looking for a features key in the geojson, but there is none.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

###################### Edit after ghybs's answer

OK, ghybs sort of solved the geojson formatting issue.  I changed the last bit of the controller to this:

```
  mongoose.model('Claim').find({
    $and:array
    }, function(err, polygons){
        polygons = {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [polygons] };
        fs.writeFile('poly.txt', polygons);
        var test = turf.merge(polygons);
        fs.writeFile('test.txt', test);
        res.json(test);
    });
};
```

I put a second fs.writeFile to see what turf.merge was returning.  The original geojson was not an array so I added the []'s.  No more turf error.  My map can't understand the output though.

Now poly.txt gives me this:

```
[object Object]
```

and test.txt contains this:

```
{ properties: null,
  geometry: undefined,
  type: 'Feature',
  _id: '56d2a2061c601e547e1099ee',
  __v: undefined },{ properties: null,
  geometry: undefined,
  type: 'Feature',
  _id: '56d2a2071c601e547e109d37',
  __v: undefined },
// This repeats 336 times
```

So I'm one step closer, I think.  Any ideas?  The map worked fine with the original data that was in poly.txt.  I'm trying to get the same thing but merged.

Answer (score 3):

The `polygons` object from your `fs.writeFile()` debug is not [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) compliant. Turf expects a GeoJSON compliant [**FeatureCollection**](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects), which must have a `features` member.

See also the [doc on Turf merge method](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_merge.html), it gives you a code sample of what a GeoJSON compliant FeatureCollection should look like.

So it looks like you should simply wrap your `polygons` object in a FeatureCollection to make it compliant:

```js
polygons = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: polygons // assuming polygons is an array
};
```

---

EDIT following the question edit

If your initial `polygons` really outputs "`[Object]`" in the geometry coordinates, rather than an array of coordinates, turf will not be able to understand your polygons geometries.

But if you say it was working before trying to merge, the issue would probably be something else.

How do you know your `polygons` are not an array? Are you sure doing `[polygons]` is the right solution?

For the next issues, please open a different question.

Comment: I added some more details to the question.  That did seem to solve the geojson formatting issue.  Now I have other problems though.

Comment: I tried removing the brackets from polygons and turf gave me this error:"
var type=obj.type;if(!this.parse[type]){throw new Error('Unknown GeoJSON type: '+obj.type);}"


The output of poly.txt is still "[object Object]"

Comment: You should probably dig further on what is your `polygons` made of, or share how you build it. Maybe try to output a `JSON.stringify` of it. You should probably do that in a new question.

Comment: That doc URL is out of date :(

Comment: @SSHThis looks like `turf.merge` has been removed from the latest version… feel free to add your findings for a replacement! :-)